# How to handle multiple invalid query params in akka http?

Tags: scala, akka, akka-http

I have query params defined in my route like so:

```
parameters(('modifiedDate.as[String].?, 'active.as[Boolean].?)) { (modifiedDate, active) =>
```

I have the following rejection handler:

```
RejectionHandler.newBuilder()
      .handle { case MalformedQueryParamRejection(param, _, _) =>
        param match {
          case "modifiedDate" => ...
          case "active" => ...
        }
      }
```

The problem is that MalformedQueryParamRejection only matches the first error, so if both query params are passed and both are incorrect:

```
some-endpoint?modifiedDate=invalid&active=invalid
```

the client will only be informed of the first error.

Is there any way of using akka http to be informed of all the query parameters that are invalid, something like `MalformedQueryParamRejection` but that reports all the invalid query params, like `MalformedQueryParamsRejection` (plural)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've raised a feature request for this:

https://github.com/akka/akka-http/issues/1490

Answer (score 2):

Use [`handleAll`](https://doc.akka.io/api/akka-http/10.0.10/akka/http/scaladsl/server/RejectionHandler$$Builder.html#handleAll[T%3C:akka.http.scaladsl.server.Rejection](f:scala.collection.immutable.Seq[T]=%3Eakka.http.scaladsl.server.Route)(implicitevidence$1:scala.reflect.ClassTag[T]):Builder.this.type). For example:

```
RejectionHandler.newBuilder()
  .handleAll[MalformedQueryParamRejection] { paramRejections =>
    // paramRejections is a Seq[MalformedQueryParamRejection]
    val malformedParamNames = paramRejections.map(_.parameterName)
    ...
  }
  ...
```